# CSS background color not sticky

Tags: html, css, flexbox, sticky

I am trying to make a navigation bar that begins mid-page stick to the top of the screen when scrolling.  I have succeeded with the navbar items, but the `.navbar` background (the color gray), scrolls with rest of the page and is replaced by the background image from the container below the navbar.  I appreciate any help with the code.

CSS:

```
.navbar_container {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    display: flex;
    margin: 0px;
    padding-top: 1px;
    padding-bottom: 1px;
    background-color: gray; 
}

.navbar_item {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 5px;
}

.image_container_bg {
    display: flex;
    margin: 0px;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

HTML (targets replaced with placeholders):

```
<div class="navbar_container">
    <a class="navbar_item" href="link">
        Home
    </a>
    <a class="navbar_item" href="link">
        About
    </a>
    <a class="navbar_item" href="link">
        Help
    </a>
</div>

<figure class="image_container_bg">
    <img src="filename">
</figure>
```

Comment: Seems to be working for me. The background is sticky along with the menu. I did notice the image goes on top of the menu is that what yo're issue is?

Comment: Yes, the background moves with the menu, but is replaced by the image when the menu sticks to the top of the screen.  The effect I'm going for is that the image goes "under" the menu, including the background, so the appearance of the menu from it's initial position remains unchanged when it sticks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply a `z-index` to the navbar (`z-index: 1` is sufficient in this case)

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  }
.navbar_container {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0px;
  padding-top: 1px;
  padding-bottom: 1px;
  background-color: gray;
  z-index: 1;
}

.navbar_item {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 5px;
}

.image_container_bg {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0px;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar_container">
  <a class="navbar_item" href="link">
        Home
    </a>
  <a class="navbar_item" href="link">
        About
    </a>
  <a class="navbar_item" href="link">
        Help
    </a>
</div>

<figure class="image_container_bg">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/800x1200/fba">
</figure>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try position fixed, Like this:

```css
.navbar_container{
  top:0;
  position: sticky;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  background-color:red;
  width:100%;
}
.navbar_item{
  padding-left:3rem;
}
.wrapper{ 
height:1000px
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="navbar_container">
    <a class="navbar_item" href="link">
        Home
    </a>
    <a class="navbar_item" href="link">
        About
    </a>
    <a class="navbar_item" href="link">
        Help
    </a>
</div>
</div>
```